# Scipy.optimize.minimize is not giving the minimum value even though it sees that value

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am using scipy.optimize.minimize to find optimal parameters for my objective function.

My code :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import Bounds

bounds = Bounds([26,26,8,6,400,100,0,25,2],[36,38,28,28,1800,800,100,50,7])

energy_history = []
x_values = []

def objective(x):
    x_trail = x.reshape(1,-1)
    x_trail = sc_X.transform(x_trail)
    y_trail = regressorSVR.predict(x_trail)
    y_trail = y_trail.reshape(1,-1)
    y_trail = sc_Y.inverse_transform(y_trail)
    return y_trail[0]


def callback(x,y):
    fobj = objective(x)
    energy_history.append(fobj)
    x_values.append(x)

x0 = np.array([26,28,15,7,400,377,40,43,4.3])
res = minimize(objective, x0, method='trust-constr',
               options={'verbose': 1}, bounds=bounds,callback=callback)

optimal_values = res.x
energy = res.fun
```

With the initial values given, the minimized value(res.fun) that I get is -7.1. I am creating a list(energy_history) to see how it is reaching this value. I see some values which are less than -7.1 in that list, but still, why is -7.1 being returned as the minimal value.

[image]

There are multiple times where objective function reached a value of -21, but why is still -7 being returned as a minimum ?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This code does not even compile. By the way, why are you using `trust-constr` when you do not have any constraints?

Comment: Hi @SuperKogito , the objective function is an SVR regression model. I cannot show post the entire code with data and training steps. It will be very lengthy. That's why I have shown the results. I have boundaries for my input parameters, that's why I am using a constrained optimization technique.

Comment: I do not think that's the same thing. Imo `Bounds` are different from `Constraints` and that is why in `Scipy` you can define them separately. I suggest trying with a different `method` and  seeing if there is a change in the behavior.

Comment: yes,  `Bounds` are different from `Constraints` . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244527/scipy-optimize-how-to-restrict-argument-values
Followed the answers of this question.

Comment: I think that the function is not convex so it is just luck if the local minimum is also global, in such case you may try multiple random initializations and hope... :)

Comment: but if it has seen a lesser value earlier than the value it's giving out as result, isn't the lesser value seen earlier should be returned as minimum?

Comment: Did you check the coordinates of those values? Could it be that they violate the bounds, and are therefore not included in the final output?

Comment: what are `sc_X` and `sc_Y` ?

Comment: they are objects of sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler class

Comment: Yes but, what they contain ? Could you show us ? Because we can't run the code

Comment: Have you checked `x_values`? I would guess, that they are slighly violating the bounds. Hence, the objective function returns a better value than -7.1. However, it is not allowed and -7.1 remains the best possible allowed value.

Comment: yes, x_values are going out of bounds, when -21 is reached. That's the reason -7.1 remains the best possible value. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take a look at the [`scipy.optimization`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/optimize.html) documentation we can see that `scipy.optimize.minimize` is listed under **local optimization**.
The main problem is that your problem is non-convex and thus `scipy.optimize.minimize` cannot guarantee the proper convergence. As it's also very much non-differentiable, many algorithms won't be suited at all.

`scipy.optimize` does provide some global optimization algorithms though that can be found on the documentation page under **global optimization**, namely `basinhopping`, `brute`, and `differential_evolution`. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52318442/5616591) for some short explanation.

Basically you can try `brute` first, just to see any systematic problems. It's basically a brute force solution and will be slow, but find your minimum. The more sophisticated method would be using `differential_evolution`. Since your function isn't really smooth, `basinhopping` might not work, but it's still worth a shot and would probably converge the fastest.