# Is there a adaptable algorithm(or code) for multiple parameters optimizatin in python?

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, scipy, genetic-algorithm, particle-swarm

I'm making a multiple parameters optimization tool for a simulator in python. I have 7 parameters and with changing the parameters, the 5 result items change. (each parameter has different boundary.)
I dont know the simulator's eqaution. So, I think I have to initiate random value and iterate an optimization algorithm until finding the parameter values which make the 5 items close to objective values. Could you advice me to the adaptable algorithm? If you give me a sample code, It would be better for me to understand.
Thanks in advance.

I tried GA, but It takes too much time and It' couldn't find adaptable value. I think It's because the boundary is too large and many parameters to change.

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries in python dedicated to numerical optimization. I would recommend `scipy.optimize` for more simple tasks like the one you are talking about and `pyomo` for more complex optimization problems.

**Problem type**

Let's look at [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html). First, you need to know whether your optimization problem is **convex** or **non-convex**. *Convex* basically means there is only a single local minimum that we want to find. *Non-convex* problems can have multiple local minimums where the optimization algorithms can get stuck.

**Convex problems**

For convex problems, we can simply refer to [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize). It requires a function `f(x)` that we want to minimize, as well as an initial value `x0` and (if available) the variable bounds.

A simple example:

```
from math import inf
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def func(x):
    simulation_result = sim(x)  # use simulator here
    objective_vector = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])  # Replace this with your objective target vector
    return np.linalg.norm(simulation_result - objective_vector)

res = minimize(func, x0=np.ones(7,1),
               bounds=[(1,2),(10,20),(0,1),(0,1),(0,inf),(-inf,0)])

if res.success:
    print(res.x)
```

**Non-convex problems**

This problem class is a lot harder and requires much more advanced algorithms. Luckily `scipy.optimize` also provides algorithms for this!
Check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56462285/5616591) and [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#global-optimization).

Comment: Thank you very much!!. but, I have questions about the code. I don't know the simulation's function. Could I insert an array in sim(x)? like simulation_result=[0.9,1,2,214,381,...]? and what means objective_value=42? my simulation results and objective_value are both arrays.

Comment: I just assume that the simulation takes some input variables `x` (your seven parameters) and outputs some result (your five result items), which I save in `simulation_result`. You do not need to know how the simulation works, you just need to obtain the output.

Comment: And I actually misread your question regarding the objective value. Let's assume you want to get close to the target vector `[1,2,3,4,5]`, then you just return `np.linalg.norm(simulation_result - np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))`.

Comment: Thanks. but how can I get the optimized parameter value sets?

Comment: `res.x` should hold the solution

Comment: I just got only [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]. I think it can't be the solution.